# Unknown Error twitter

Tags: twitter, sharekit

I have a question, I know there a new version of ShareKit 2.0, but I only use facebook and twitter, I adapted the code to my needs and I have corrected some mistakes, I will not change the version because it would change everything that I have already done and it works. But I can not correct this: UnKnown Error.
I had already had and just change by OAMutableURLRequest * oRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @ "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"] in SHKTwitter.m and was solved.

Could you advise me to do without having to switch to the new version?. 
Excuse my English, I'm learning.

Comment: I solved my mistake, checked: https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json ("errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview. "," code ": 68}]}) just switched to " https://api.twitter.com/1.1/ statuses / update.json ".

Comment: It helped me this information: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/18448

Comment: Changes: https://dev.twitter.com/calendar